# Why should time-subscript notation be avoided in Bellman equations?

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics

when I learned Bellman equations for macro, my lecturers were pretty loose about notation and switched between recursive and time-series notation. However, Prof Ben Moll says in his slides on Slide 15 below, that the time-subscript notation should be avoided, but I'm not sure why.

https://benjaminmoll.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Lecture2_EC442_Moll.pdf

Can anyone explain why, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It’s literally explained on the next slide

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the general intuition:

**1. Finite Horizon Case**

It is necessary to include the time subscript here because $V_t(k_t)$ and $V_{t+1}(k_{t+1})$ have different number of time periods ahead of them. Suppose everything ends at time $T$, then the former has $T-t$ periods ahead, and the latter has $T-t-1$ periods ahead of it. As is the case for slide 15.

**2. Infinite Horizon Case**

Here you can use the recursive form. There is no end in sight i.e for both $V_t(k_t)$ and $V_{t+1}(k_{t+1})$, the time ahead of them is infinity. So the value function are same because they face the same future (The argument inside the value function is NOT i.e $k$ $\neq$ $k'$). We say the value function is time invariant. This is not true for finite horizon case.

**3. Summary**

Drop the time subscript if the value function agents face are the same, which happens in stationary environments. So for example if you were to solve an OLG model in a recursive form, you would not drop the time subscript, because value functions are different for each individual since they are at different ages in different periods.

**4. Further Information**

Formally, this is discussed in Stokey and Lucas textbook in either Chapter 3 or 4.